# Java lock/concurrency issue when searching array with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I am new to Java and trying to write a method that finds the maximum value in a 2D array of longs.

The method searches through each row in a separate thread, and the threads maintain a shared current maximal value. Whenever a thread finds a value larger than its own local maximum, it compares this value with the shared local maximum and updates its current local maximum and possibly the shared maximum as appropriate. I need to make sure that appropriate synchronization is implemented so that the result is correct regardless of how to computations interleave.

My code is verbose and messy, but for starters, I have this function:

```
   static long sharedMaxOf2DArray(long[][] arr, int r){

     MyRunnableShared[] myRunnables = new MyRunnableShared[r];
     for(int row = 0; row < r; row++){
       MyRunnableShared rr = new MyRunnableShared(arr, row, r);
       Thread t = new Thread(rr);
       t.start();
       myRunnables[row] = rr;
     }

     return myRunnables[0].sharedMax; //should be the same as any other one (?)

   }
```

For the adapted runnable, I have this:

```
   public static class MyRunnableShared implements Runnable{
     long[][] theArray; 
     private int row; 
     private long rowMax; 
     public long localMax; 
     public long sharedMax; 
     private static Lock sharedMaxLock = new ReentrantLock(); 
     MyRunnableShared(long[][] a, int r, int rm){
        theArray = a; 
        row = r;
        rowMax = rm;
      }
      public void run(){
        localMax = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < rowMax; i++){
          if(theArray[row][i] > localMax){
            localMax = theArray[row][i];
            sharedMaxLock.lock();
            try{
              if(localMax > sharedMax)
                sharedMax = localMax;
            }
            finally{
              sharedMaxLock.unlock(); 
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    }
```

I thought this use of a lock would be a safe way to prevent multiple threads from messing with the `sharedMax` at a time, but upon testing/comparing with a non-concurrent maximum-finding function on the same input, I found the results to be incorrect. I'm thinking the problem might come from the fact that I just say

```
...
t.start();
myRunnables[row] = rr; 
...
```

in the `sharedMaxOf2DArray` function. Perhaps a given thread needs to finish before I put it in the array of myRunnables; otherwise, I will have "captured" the wrong sharedMax? Or is it something else? I'm not sure on the timing of things..

Comment: Can you show the definition of class & instance variables of `MyRunnableSHared`?

Comment: i think you are right, when you launch threads there is no guarantee what will be executed first and its likely that you get to the return instruction in the main thread before the other threads finish.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this in multiple threads instead of just one?

Comment: probably just to learn or to take advantage of data parallelism in big big matrix @DiegoBasch

Comment: @amit Oh...oops. I don't know why I didn't paste over that important chunk. Editing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a typo or not, but your `Runnable` implementation declares `sharedMax` as an instance variable:

```
public long sharedMax;
```

rather than a shared one:

```
public static long sharedMax;
```

In the former case, each Runnable gets its own copy and will not "see" the values of others. Changing it to the latter should help. Or, change it to:

```
public long[] sharedMax; // array of size 1 shared across all threads
```

and you can now create an array of size one outside the loop and pass it in to each Runnable to use as shared storage.

*As an aside*: please note that there will be tremendous lock contention since every thread checks the common sharedMax value by holding a lock for every iteration of its loop. This will likely lead to poor performance. You'd have to measure, but I'd surmise that letting each thread find the row maximum and then running a final pass to find the "max of maxes" might actually be comparable or quicker.

Comment: This is not a good use case for a low level primitive like RentrantLock and sharing state via a static variable is bad practice. For one thing the shared static prevents the entire code block from being thread safe (eg if it's in it's own method it can't be called twice simultaneously). See my answer for a thread safe SSCCE that uses `Future`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

From JavaDocs:

> public interface Callable
>
> A task that returns a result and may
>   throw an exception. Implementors define a single method with no
>   arguments called call.
>
> The Callable interface is similar to Runnable, in that both are
>   designed for classes whose instances are potentially executed by
>   another thread. A Runnable, however, does not return a result and
>   cannot throw a checked exception.

Well, you can use Callable to calculate your result from one 1darray and wait with an ExecutorService for the end. You can now compare each result of the  Callable to fetch the maximum. The code may look like this:

```
Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
long[][] myArray = new long[5][5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myArray[i] = new long[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        myArray[i][j] = random.nextLong();
    }
}

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(myArray.length);
List<Future<Long>> myResults = new ArrayList<>();
// create a callable for each 1d array in the 2d array
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        Callable<Long> callable = new SearchCallable(myArray[i]);
    Future<Long> callResult = executor.submit(callable);
    myResults.add(callResult);
}
// This will make the executor accept no new threads
// and finish all existing threads in the queue
executor.shutdown();
// Wait until all threads are finish
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
}
// now compare the results and fetch the biggest one
long max = 0;
for (Future<Long> future : myResults) {
    try {
        max = Math.max(max, future.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // something bad happend...!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println("The result is " + max);
```

And your Callable:

```
public class SearchCallable implements Callable<Long> {

    private final long[] mArray;

    public SearchCallable(final long[] pArray) {
        mArray = pArray;
    }

    @Override
    public Long call() throws Exception {
        long max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length; i++) {
            max = Math.max(max, mArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("I've got the maximum " + max + ", and you guys?");
        return max;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has serious lock contention and thread safety issues. Even worse, it doesn't actually wait for any of the threads to finish before the `return myRunnables[0].sharedMax` which is a really bad race condition. Also, using explicit locking via `ReentrantLock` or even `synchronized` blocks is usually the wrong way of doing things unless you're implementing something low level (eg your own/new concurrent data structure)

Here's a version that uses the `Future` concurrent primitive and an `ExecutorService` to handle the thread creation. The general idea is:

1. Submit a number of concurrent jobs to your `ExecutorService`
2. Add the `Future` returned backed from `submit(...)` to a `List`
3. Loop through the list calling `get()` on each `Future` and aggregating the result

This version has the added benefit that there is no lock contention (or locking in general) between the worker threads as each just returns back the max for its slice of the array.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PMax {
    public static long pmax(final long[][] arr, int numThreads) {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
        try {
            List<Future<Long>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Long>>();
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
                // put sub-array in a final so the inner class can see it:
                final long[] subArr = arr[i];
                list.add(pool.submit(new Callable<Long>() {
                    public Long call() {
                        long max = Long.MIN_VALUE;
                        for(int j=0;j<subArr.length;j++) {
                            if( subArr[j] > max ) {
                                max = subArr[j];
                            }
                        }
                        return max;
                    }
                }));
            }
            // find the max of each slice's max:
            long max = Long.MIN_VALUE;
            for(Future<Long> future : list) {
                long threadMax = future.get();
                System.out.println("threadMax: " + threadMax);
                if( threadMax > max ) {
                    max = threadMax;
                }
            }
            return max;
        } catch( RuntimeException e ) {
            throw e;
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            pool.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 1000;
        int y = 1000;
        long max = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        long[][] foo = new long[x][y];
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++) {
                long r = (long)(Math.random() * 100000000);
                if( r > max ) {
                    // save this to compare against pmax:
                    max = r; 
                }
                foo[i][j] = r;
            }
        }
        int numThreads = 32;
        long pmax = pmax(foo, numThreads);
        System.out.println("max:  " + max);
        System.out.println("pmax: " + pmax);
    }
}
```

**Bonus:** If you're calling this method repeatedly then it would probably make sense to pull the `ExecutorService` creation out of the method and have it be reused across calls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that definetly is an issue - but without more code it is hard to understand if it is the only thing.

There is basically a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) between the access of `thread[0]` (and this read of `sharedMax`) and the modification of the `sharedMax` in other threads.

Think what happens if the scheduler decides to let no let any thread run for now - so when you are done creating the threads, you will return the answer without modifying it even once! (of course there are other possible scenarios...)

You can overcome it by [`join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)ing all threads before returning an answer.